# ScikitLearn - RandomForestRegressor score different in and out of grid search

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I am using `RandomForestRegressor` (`scikit-learn` python package). I am looking for the best values for hyperparameters `n_estimators` and `min_samples_split` for fitting my regressor on a train dataset ( `X_train`, `y_train` ) :

```
  param_grid = { 'n_estimators' : range( 10 , 201 ) ,
                 'min_samples_split' : range( 2 , 11 ) }


  rfr = RandomForestRegressor()

  best_score = 0
  best_param = {}

  for param in ParameterGrid( param_grid ):
      rfr.set_params( **g )
      rfr.fit( X_train , y_train )
      score = rfr.score( X_train , y_train )

  if score > best_score :
      best_score = score
      best_param = param

  print( 'best_score : {0}'.format( best_score ) )
  print( 'best_parameters : {0}'.format( best_param ) )
```

I am not using cross validation on purpose.

The best hyper parameters are in the `best_param` variable , the corresponding score in the `best_score` variable.

After that, I set the hyper parameters of my regressor using the best ones :

```
rfr.set_params( **best_param )
```

I fit the regressor on my train dataset:

```
rfr.fit( X_train , y_train )
```

Finally just to check I obtain the score of the regressor with the best hyper parameters:

```
rfr.score( X_train , y_train )
```

The score is not the same as the one calculated in the grid : 0.806 out of grid versus 0.963 in the grid.

I do not understand why. The hyper parameters are the best ones, and the dataset used to calculate these best parameters is the same. Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer to my question : there is randomness in **RandomForestRegressor()**.

Using the **random_state** hyper parameter fix the problem :

```
rfr = RandomForestRegressor( random_state = 123 )
```

What is surprising is the difference of score obtained from different values of the **random_state** hyper parameter. It means my best hyper parameters **n_estimators** and **min_samples_split** are strongly depend on the **random_state** hyper parameter.

I guess it is something I will have to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Without cross validation you are effectively selecting the best hyperparameters for just one set of training data so its overfitting. However, because of the `random_state` parameter not being set, you are basically using different samples of your training data each time.

See this cross-validated question: [How bad is hyperparameter tuning outside cross validation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137481/how-bad-is-hyperparameter-tuning-outside-cross-validation) Maybe you should try it with CV and see if that still happens.

Comment: Thanks for the link about hyperparameter tuning outside cross validation. I am not using cross validation because my data is some kind of time serie. I have to check this link that seems promising : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html

Comment: Oh cool. I don't know much about cv for time series. Could maybe be an interesting question to post here!